# Get data from Access database by Like method

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

Greeting I have some problem to use VBA excel get data from MS Access
use like method to get data

Sample
My data have record 'LOT/000'
input 'LOT' don't get report
input 'LOT/000' can get report

Source

```
Sub getdata()


Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim DbPath As String
Dim shI As Worksheet

Set shI = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")

DbPath = "C:\mydatabase.accdb"

Set cn = New ADODB.Connection

With cn

.Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
.ConnectionString = DbPath
.Open

End With

Set Sort = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Report")

Query = "Select * FROM Film_build WHERE film_id like '" & Sort.Cells(2, 2) & "'"

Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

rs.Open Query, cn, adOpenDynamic, adLockBatchOptimistic

shI.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs
 

End Sub
```

My MS Access query setting

```
SELECT *
FROM Film_build
WHERE film_id like 'LOT*';
```

hope this to helpful my problem.

Comment: `like '" & Sort.Cells(2, 2) & "*'"`

Comment: Thank for reply but same problem can't get data 
when i use 'LOT' but work on 'LOT/000'

Comment: Now can ran code use like '" & Sort.Cells(2, 2) & "%'"

Comment: ADO recordset use %, DAO recordset use *.